# 9147 Segmentation Fault : 11 Construct Binary tree from inorder and preorder traversals

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

Given inorder and preorder traversal of a Binary Tree, construct the Binary Tree.

While constructing a tree from inorder and preorder traversal, i think i have written it properly  but why is it giving a segmentatation fault. Please help.
below is my code for the same :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Node {
 public :
 int data;
 Node* left;
 Node* right;

 Node(int data)
 {
    this->data = data;
    left = right = NULL;
 }
};

void Inorder(Node* root)
{
  if (root == NULL)
  {
    return;
  }

  Inorder(root->left);
  cout << root->data << " ";
  Inorder(root->right);
}

 Node* buildTreeHelper( int inorder[], int preorder[], int InS, int InE, int PreS, int PreE)
 {

  if (InS > InE)
  {
     return NULL;
  }

 int rootData = preorder[PreS];

 int lIns = InS;
 int rootIndex = -1;
 for (int i = InS ; i < InE ; i++)
  {
     if (inorder[i] == rootData)
       {
         rootIndex = i;
         break;
       }
  }
    int lIne = rootIndex - 1;
    int lPres = PreS + 1;
    int lPree = lIne - lIns + lPres;
    int rIns = rootIndex + 1;
    int rIne = InE;
    int rPres = lPree  + 1;
    int rPree = PreE;


   Node* root = new Node(rootData);
   root->left = buildTreeHelper(inorder, preorder, lIns, lIne, lPres, lPree);
   root->right = buildTreeHelper(inorder, preorder, rIns, rIne, rPres, rPree);

    return root;
}

Node* buildTree(int inorder[], int preorder[], int size)
{
    return buildTreeHelper(inorder, preorder, 0, size - 1, 0, size - 1);
}
int main()
{

    int inorder[] = {4, 2, 5, 1, 8, 6, 9, 3, 7};
    int preorder[] = {1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 8, 9, 7};

   Node* root = buildTree(inorder, preorder, 9);
    Inorder(root);
    delete root;
    return 0;
}
```

I am unable to identify what's the error, please help me out of this.

Comment: What actions have you taken so far to isolate the exact line of code that results in a segfault?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: If it was written properly, it wouldn't crash. It's an oddly common thing I see here. Must be the thinking that successful* compilation equates to "correct" code. * Generally a bare-bones compiles that doesn't even have a lot of, if any, warnings activated.

Comment: Segmentation faults are a blessing from the Giver Of Data. They prove without a sliver of doubt that you have a bug. This is much better state than having a bug and not knowing it. And if the segfaults are consistent, they make it a lot easier to track down with a debugger.

Comment: In this case running the program under the GNU debugger (GDB) almost instantly pinpoints the problem as a improperly controlled recursion leading to a stack overflow (ridiculously long backtrace when the debugger stops because the program crashed).

Comment: @sweenish -- I try to explain it this way:  If someone asked you to write a program to add two numbers, but instead the program subtracts two numbers, the code compiled without error -- that doesn't mean the program did the right thing.  The OP may think that the program is a human being that says "I know you meant to do this instead of what you wrote, so I will make the correction for you".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that at least one of your problems is that in the loop to find the root index in the in-order list of data, you don't actually check the last element (i.e. it should be `i <= InE`.)

Also, I can't say that your `lPree` calc is correct, because the names you have chosen are so unhelpful that I don't even want to read that line.

And, please don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`. I don't know which compiler/IDE is it that encourages use of this particular header, but I've seen it in other (beginner) people's code and in my opinion, it's no good. Please just use standard headers. In this case, that would be `iostream` (maybe with a `using std::cout;` thrown in.)

By the way, at the end of the program, you are only freeing the single root node. That is obviously insufficient and incorrect. You have to traverse and free the whole tree (you could do that from the `Node` destructor, but I wouldn't recommend a recursive call in a destructor. You might be OK in this simple program.)

Comment: [Simple example](https://godbolt.org/z/ntMreq) of how easy it is to get a potentially confusing error with `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` Worse this code will work just fine up until c++17, so you upgrade the compiler and all of a sudden your working code doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks i got the bug !!